# Alarm Manager vs Job Scheduler vs ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: android

this question is just to get some ideas on these concepts to see what people in the industry use these for.

If you can just give a few example uses for each of these, I would greatly appreciate it. I know how they work and did read the google documentation on them but I still seem to be having a hard time picking one over the other. I don't need you to explain to me how they work. I am simply asking for a few of their example uses. How you ended up incorporating them into your apps and why you picked them over the others.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

**AlarmManager**

Using the AlarmManager to Schedule Tasks at the System Level

The AlarmManager provides access to system-level alarm services. Using the AlarmManager allows an application to schedule tasks that may need to run or repeat beyond the scope of its lifecycle. This allows the application to perform some function even after the application process or all of its Android components have been cleaned up by the system.

Typically, the AlarmManager is used to fire off a PendingIntent that will start up a Service in the future. The AlarmManager triggers Services based on an elapsed interval or at a specific clock time. Both of these options also have the ability to wake up the device when it is asleep if the alarm is urgent.

The benefits of the AlarmManager come into play when using inexact intervals or times to fire off Services. The Android system tries to batch alarms with similar intervals or times together in order to preserve battery life. By batching alarms from multiple applications, the system can avoid frequent device wake and networking.

One concern to consider while using the AlarmManager is that alarms are wiped out during device reboots. Applications need to register the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE permission in their Android Manifest and reschedule their alarms in a BroadcastReceiver.

Another concern is that a poorly designed alarm could cause battery drain. While the AlarmManager does have the ability to wake devices and set an exact time for an alarm, the documentation mentions that developers should be wary of these features when performing networking. Aside from draining a device’s battery by avoiding batch alarms, setting an exact time for an application to sync with a server could put high strain on a server if every application installation tries to sync with the server around the same time! This can be avoided by adding some randomness to alarm intervals or times.

AlarmManager is a great candidate for scheduling if an application needs to perform a local event at an exact time or inexact interval. Alarm clock or reminder applications are great examples for AlarmManager usage. However, the documentation discourages using AlarmManager for scheduling network-related tasks. Let’s take a look at some better options for networking.

**Job Scheduler**

JobScheduler helps perform background work in an efficient way, especially networking. JobServices are scheduled to run based on criteria declared in JobInfo.Builder(). These criteria include performing the JobService only when the device is charging, idle, connected to a network or connected to an unmetered network. JobInfo can also include minimum delays and certain deadlines for performing the JobService. Jobs will queue up in the system to be performed at a later time if none of these criteria are met. The system will also try to batch these jobs together in the same manner that alarms are scheduled in order to save battery life when making a network connection.

Developers might be concerned about a scheduler that frequently delays firing off its JobServices. If jobs are frequently delayed and data stale as a result, it would be nice to know about such things. JobScheduler will return information about the JobService such as if it was rescheduled or failed. JobScheduler has back-off and retry logic for handling these scenarios, or developers could handle those scenarios themselves.

Subclassing JobService requires an override of its onStartJob(JobParams params) and onStopJob(JobParams params) methods. onStartJob() is where callback logic for jobs should be placed, and it runs on the main thread. Developers are responsible for threading when dealing with long running jobs. Return true to onStartJob() if separate thread processing needs to occur, or false if processing can occur on the main thread and there is no more work to be done for this job. Developers must also call jobFinished(JobParameters params, boolean needsReschedule) when the job is complete and determine whether or not to reschedule more jobs. onStopJob() will get called to stop or cleanup tasks when initial JobInfo parameters are no longer met, such as a user unplugging their device if that parameter is a requirement.

There might be a lot to think about when implementing a JobService, but it comes with a lot more flexibility than AlarmManager. Another handy feature is that scheduled jobs persist through system reboots.

There is at least one drawback to using JobScheduler. As of the writing of this post, it’s compatable only with API level 21 and higher. Here you can find the distribution of Android devices running various API levels. While there is technically no backport of JobScheduler, a similar tool is GCM Network Manager.

**[REFERENCE LINK](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/choosing-the-right-background-scheduler-in-android/#comment-2679781730)**

Comment: currently, the `WorkManager` is a universal tool for scheduling which uses `AlarmManager` and `JobScheduler` depending on the platform.

Comment: @davee44 Yes, but `WorkManager` works with min. time 15 minutes between starts.